# Polar plot without grid in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to turn of the grid for polar plots in matplotlib? I tried `matplotlib.pyplot.rgrids([], [])`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From your `axes` instance, call `grid(False)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.grid(False)

r = np.arange(0,1,0.001)
theta = 2*2*np.pi*r

ax.plot(theta,r)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you want to remove the labels, you just have to call `ax.set_xticklabels([])` and `ax.set_yticklabels([])`.

Comment: and if you want to remove the outline border, use `ax.axis("off")`